# Script for using AesCrypt on a lot of files

Tags: linux, bash, encryption, bash-scripting, aes

I'm just learning bash and I'm about to renew my backup security standards at home, just in case something happens.

I have two external HDDs for Backup. I want to encrypt the files first on my laptop (which has a disk encryption applied to) and then move them to the HDD's so that there is no hidden (deleted) unencrypted data on there.

I could simply use a Disk Encryption but that's not what I intend to do for several reasons.

Beside that, how does a script looks like which encrypts all files (not the folders itself) down to the last subfolder from a given root folder using AESCrypt oder maybe something similar with AES-256-CBC?

Comment: So you want only the files on the 2nd drive to be encrypted not the drive?  if so a simple rsync -raXxHhD /drive_1  /drive_2 --exclude=/path/to/{contents_of_excludes.txt}

Comment: Thanks, now I just have to encrypt the files beforehand. I wasn't aware of this command before

Comment: If you are wanting to keep all the encrypted bits as is use `dd`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure you can use pure bash to encrypt. I'm sure it's possible, but I can offer another solution for you.

---

Bash Solution:

```
openssl enc -nosalt -aes-128-cbc -in test -out test.enc -p
```

Found this  at [stack-overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343894/aes-encrypt-with-openssl-command-line-tool-and-decrypt-in-java)

---

Python Solution:

Instead of trying to stumble around bash, looking for a way to encrypt, have you tried looking at Python? A native Linux language, that supports encryption and many other things.

So in python, to do what you're looking to do.

```
apt-get install python-pip
pip install pyCrypto
```

Then from there, there's some things you're going to want to look at.

[AES Encryption in Python](http://www.codekoala.com/posts/aes-encryption-python-using-pycrypto/)

You're also going to want to look into the function "Walk" from the "OS" module.

[OS Walk Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm)

And finally to make it so you can easily access your files with a simple password of your choice

```
#!/bin/python
# Python 2 example
from Crypto.Hash import MD5
secret = MD5.new(raw_input('Password: ')).hexdigest()
```

Then simply encrypt with secret every file if you choose, and the key will be the same for each file.

Comment: This one comes in handy as I need to learn Python in the next couple of months! I think I can combine that with Rsync somehow to fully automate the process of encrypting and copying. Maybe I don't even need to use Rsync and can solve it solely with Python.

Comment: @user645056 Yes python can be used solely to create such a program by using sockets and the other libraries I listed above. If you're looking to backup and encrypt data, there's a program called spider oak